# tinymce not working on firefox

Tags: tinymce

I have three textareas using tinymce as text area.  They all work in chrome but not on firefox.  I am loading the text from mysql using php code.  The first textarea loads ok and works, but the other two briefly flashes the contents and then it's gone. I'm not able to insert anything in the box.  Here is the script:

```
<!-- Load TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript"
src="functions/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : 'functions/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
plugins : '-examples', // - tells TinyMCE to skip the loading of the plugin
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
theme_advanced_buttons1 :
"mylistbox,mysplitbutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,
justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link, 
unlink",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "code,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom"



    });

    $('textarea.tinymce2').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : 'functions/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
plugins : '-examples', // - tells TinyMCE to skip the loading of the plugin
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
theme_advanced_buttons1:
"mylistbox,mysplitbutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,
justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "code,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom"



    }); 

    $('textarea.tinymce3').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : 'functions/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
plugins : '-examples', // - tells TinyMCE to skip the loading of the plugin
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
theme_advanced_buttons1:
"mylistbox,mysplitbutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,
justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "code,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom"



    }); 

});
</script>
 <!-- /TinyMCE -->
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks Randy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug either in tinyMCE or in the latest FF update.

Either way the workaround is to change some CSS value (by for example making the editable content area bigger / smaller by dragging) to let it redraw the content.

There is also a [ticket about it](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5082) on the TinyMCE bug tracker. Until that bug is fixed you would have to go for the workaround.

Answer (score -1):

your javascript is off. if you are using web developer tools addon, then check on the top left side of the browser and click on disable > disable javascript > uncheck disable all scripts. that will work.