# TinyMCE not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, tinymce, rich-text-editor

Tinymce (version - 3.1) gets loaded while opened and displays the desired content. In just one second the content goes blank and the editor closes. This issue occurs only in Firefox browser. Any other browser, it works fine. Also first time in FireFox, it works fine and from the second time opened, it cannot persist the content and gets closed. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check this link might be it will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002219/tinymce-not-working-on-firefox

Comment: what code do you use to initialize your editor?